# Prove there is only one MST in a graph with distinct weights

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected, connected and weighted graph.
>
> Let also $(e_{1},\ldots , e_{|E|})$ be some sort of the edges of $G$.
>
> Let $w, w' \colon E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
> $$w(e_{1})<w(e_{2})< \dots < w(e_{|E|})$$
> $$w'(e_{1})<w'(e_{2})< \dots < w'(e_{|E|})$$
>
> Prove that the two MST's resulting from the weights function are identical.
>
> Deduce that for every sort of the edges there is only one unique MST, meaning only one $T = \mathrm{MST}(e_{1},\ldots , e_{|E|})$.

My idea for the first part was to assume by the contradiction that there are $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ such that $T_{1} \neq T_{2}$, each for $w$ and $w'$. I wasn't able to come to a contradiction, so I thought maybe I should use Kruskal's algorithm.

Any help would be appreciated.

I realize the intuition but I can't formally write it.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kruskal's algorithm goes over all edges in increasing order of weight. For each such edge, it adds it to the tree being build if it doesn't close a cycle.

As you can see, the outcome of the algorithm depends only on the relative order of the weights, not on their values.

Formally speaking (if the above informal argument isn't considered convincing enough), you can prove the claim that you're after by induction on the number of iterations of the main loop in Kruskal's algorithm. You show that an edge is added when the weights are $w$ iff it is added when the weights are $w'$.

Comment: Thnak you, will do!